# Debugging WPF styles that have been applied to an element

Tags: windows, software-development, .net, wpf

In WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation), elements can get styles from various sources, similar to HTML elements that get styles from CSS.

In HTML/CSS, most browsers have great support to find out where a style comes from, e.g. like this:

[image: CSS styles that have been applied to HTML]

I'm looking for a similar tool that does that for XPF/XAML. I'd like to see which styles are applied and which are not and where they come from.

I'd not like to browse through the whole element tree and figure it out myself, but instead see all the necessary information immediately.

I love gratis tools, but I might even pay for such a thing, so commercial answers are ok.

I have tried [Snoop WPF](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), but it only displays the properties and not where they come from.